# AndroidManifest does not generate launcher icon

Tags: android, android-manifest

My AndroidManifest.xml file does not create a launcher icon as it should.

The XML is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.jbrooksuk.iTunesTweet"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/itticon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity android:name=".iTunesTweet"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="com.jbrooksuk.iTunesTweet" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name=".OAUTH"
        android:label="@string/oauth_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="itt" android:host="twtr" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.jbrooksuk.iTunesTweet.AndroidMusicReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.android.music.metachanged" />
            <action
                android:name="com.android.music.playstatechanged" />
            <action
                android:name="com.android.music.playbackcomplete" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.jbrooksuk.iTunesTweet.HeroMusicReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.htc.music.metachanged" />
            <action
                android:name="com.htc.music.playbackcomplete" />
            <action
                android:name="com.htc.music.playstatechanged" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.jbrooksuk.iTunesTweet.iTTService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.jbrooksuk.iTunesTweet.playstatechanged" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

The icon should take the user to the main class; com.jbrooksuk.iTunesTweet but no icon is even created.

When I run the code from ADB the layout is displayed though!

James

Comment: Try getting rid of `<category android:name="com.jbrooksuk.iTunesTweet" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very weird but installing the application via ADB works a treat, but running it via Eclipse does not. Bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where my app would just have the default package icon, and my solution was to rename the icon from "icon" to "launcher_icon" (The name doesn't matter).

I guess eclipse is able to get into a strange state sometimes. :(

Hope it solves your problem!

Also be aware that most launchers might not pick up on an icon change.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Manifest. 
Find Application tab.
Click Browse next to the 'icon' space
Choose @drawable/web_hi_res_512
Error should go away and not affect your App Run attempt.

Good Luck!